# AWS Cognito: Developer Authenticated Identities

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

These are the calls I'm making to get the access token from AWS Cognito. I am implementing the [Developer Authenticated Identities workflow](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/developer-authenticated-identities.html)
where I authenticate the user on my backend. My code:

```
cognitoIndentityClient = Aws::CognitoIdentity::Client.new(
        region: 'us-east-1',
        credentials: permanent_aws_creds,
    )
developerProviderName = '1.Got From Developer Provider Name under Custom in Cognito Console'
identityPoolId = 'us-east-1:Xxxxx'

resp = cognitoIndentityClient.get_open_id_token_for_developer_identity(
        identity_pool_id: identityPoolId,
        logins: {
            developerProviderName =>  UniqueIdentityTokenProviderFromMYBackend
        }
    )

resp2 = cognitoIndentityClient.get_credentials_for_identity(
        {
            identity_id: resp['identity_id'],
            logins: {
                'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com' => resp['token']
            }
        }
    )
```

My Question:
1. How can I create a user in the user pool (enable MFA and all that) after the above calls? I can see that Identities are created in my console but I'm lost after that.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check that in identity pool configuration in custom tab of Authentication providers section you have the developer provider name set and it matches with the value in your code above? This might be one possible reason for the error.

To answer your other question. You do not need to implement developer authenticated identities to use the 'User Pools' feature of Cognito. These are two independent features. Cognito developer authenticated identities allows you to federate your own authentication system with Cognito identity. If you want Cognito to manage your users and allow username and password based sign-up, sign-ins and MFA  for you, 'User Pools' feature will be correct choice. The user managed by User pools can also federate with Cognito identity.

Comment: Thank you, I did. All I had to do was substitute cognito-identity.amazonaws.com for developerProviderName key in get_credentials_for_identity(). I have a question about users though, can you help me with that, please?

Comment: Also, I've modified the code to reflect it. There were zero ruby examples so this could be helpful to someone.

Comment: Sure, thanks.  Also can you please keep the original error message in the question so that is is useful for someone coming across the same problem. Currently there are no ruby sdk for user pools. But it is available in android, iOS and javascript.